# VSIX Installer - 'Microsoft Analysis Services Projects' fails to install

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools, vsix

The latest Microsoft VS2017 VSIX installer cannot install SSAS project template (Microsoft Analysis Services Projects). I can replicate this issue consistently with the installer.

**Note: I already followed the instructions mentioned in similar questions on Stack Overflow including downloading the SSDT installer and running each mini-installer manually from C:\Temp**

I can replicate this issue consistently with the Microsoft offline SSDT installer as well as the SSAS project template installer from Nuget.

They both install the same component named 'Microsoft Analysis Services Projects'

This is the error:
The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core.dll' already exists.

I have tried deleting all the files under:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\

and rerun the installer. However, the installer creates the file and then a moment later fails to install because the file already exists....

I need to get an installer that works without tripping over itself ;) LOL

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 trying to install Analysis Services project templates.

Here is the log file from the failed installation:

```
11/27/2018 4:07:16 PM - System restore is not supported on this system
11/27/2018 4:07:16 PM - Failed to create system restore point: 0x80131524
11/27/2018 4:08:20 PM - Package '04a86fc2-dbd5-4222-848e-911638e487fe,version=2.2' failed to install. System.IO.IOException: The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core.dll' already exists.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.<InstallCoreInternal>g__install|27_1(PackagePart part, Boolean saveExtensionManifest, <>c__DisplayClass27_0& , <>c__DisplayClass27_1& , <>c__DisplayClass27_2& , <>c__DisplayClass27_3& , <>c__DisplayClass27_4& )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.InstallCoreInternal(String localPath, String installDir, InstallablePackage pkg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.FileInstaller.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<InstallCore>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.FileInstaller.DoAction(Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.FileInstaller.InstallCore(String localPath, String installDir, InstallablePackage pkg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.InstallerBase.InstallHelper(InstallData installData)
11/27/2018 4:08:20 PM - Skipping cache of package 'Component.04a86fc2-dbd5-4222-848e-911638e487fe,version=2.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
11/27/2018 4:08:52 PM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package '04a86fc2-dbd5-4222-848e-911638e487fe' failed to install
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Answer (score 3):

After uninstalling VS2017 and reinstalling it works fine. Hope this helps someone ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I had the same issue with VS2019.   I was upgrading VS2015 to VS2019.  I had to uninstall everything VS2015 first (no sure if required).  I also uninstalled BIDS (2015).   Only then I uninstalled VS2019.  Then installed VS2019 again.  Then installed extension "Microsoft Analysis Services Project".  I just made sure I do only 1 thing at a time (no sure if required).